# How can I add custom fields for only top level taxonomy in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, custom-fields

I created a custom taxonomy. There are only 5 top level categories but tons of subcategories. Is it possible to add editable custom fields for only top level categories via Advanced Custom Fields or custom code solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Will there be more "top level" categories in the future? because if not, you can just specify those 5 categories for your field.

Comment: Yep, there will be more top level categories in future and that's why I don't want to specify IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a request that has been made many times before, but sadly never implemented by Elliot.

But you can create custom location rules, which other people have made before - If you want to create a parent level rule for acf, you could consider implementing this from github.

I know that other people has used it before.

Check the github out -> [Here](https://github.com/LightboxDigital/ACF-Taxonomy-Depth-Rule)

Hopefully it will be implemented in the future, but for now it is not possible without creating your own rules.

Hope that it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! I also found couple useful links about custom location rules for ACF which may help somebody with same problem: [first link](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/assigning-custom-fields-to-childparents/) and [second link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/custom-location-rules/)

Comment: Hello, is there any native WordPress functions to achieve this ?